# Ruby Glimmer, running glimmer examples yields stacktrace

Tags: ruby

I am following the presentation of the RubyConf workshop detailed here: https://github.com/AndyObtiva/how-to-build-desktop-applications-in-ruby and am already stuck at the second command. I issued `gem install glimmer-dsl-libui` which ran successfully and installed glimmer (2.7.6) and glimmer-dsl-libui (0.11.8), but the command `glimmer examples` gives me the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    27: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin/glimmer:23:in `<main>'
    26: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin/glimmer:23:in `load'
    25: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/bin/glimmer:24:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/bin/glimmer:24:in `require_relative'
    23: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer-dsl-libui.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    21: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    20: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/dsl/libui/dsl.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/dsl/libui/dsl.rb:23:in `each'
    18: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/dsl/libui/dsl.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
    17: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    16: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    15: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/dsl/libui/tab_item_expression.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    13: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    12: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy/tab_item_proxy.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    10: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     9: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy.rb:425:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy.rb:425:in `each'
     7: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy.rb:425:in `block in <top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     5: from /Users/marion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
     4: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy/text_proxy.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy/text_proxy.rb:28:in `<module:Glimmer>'
     2: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy/text_proxy.rb:29:in `<module:LibUI>'
     1: from /Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy/text_proxy.rb:33:in `<class:ControlProxy>'
/Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/glimmer-dsl-libui-0.11.8/lib/glimmer/libui/control_proxy/text_proxy.rb:35:in `<class:TextProxy>': uninitialized constant Glimmer::LibUI::ControlProxy::TextProxy::PerfectShaped (NameError)
```

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Looks like maybe there is just a missing `require` in the source code?

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem but the [setup](https://github.com/AndyObtiva/how-to-build-desktop-applications-in-ruby#setup-glimmer-dsl-for-libui) section specifically asks to install version 0.11.4 (via `gem install glimmer-dsl-libui -v0.11.4`) whereas you are running 0.11.8.

Comment: @engineersmnky which source code? I'm new to this, I have just been told to run this command without any explanation

Comment: @Stefan I dunno, but if I understand the message correctly it can't find a certain class. If the change from 0.11.4 to 0.11.8 breaks the class tree like this it does sound like Glimmer isn't a system anybody should use.

Comment: Just give it a try with 0.11.4 and see if the error remains

Comment: Same kind of problem with ruby 2.6.1 and `gem install glimmer-dsl-libui -v0.11.4` but with another NameError => `uninitialized constant Glimmer::DSL::Libui::Expression (NameError)`. tried also 0.11.8 and 0.11.3 with no success

Comment: Note that description state 'Install glimmer-dsl-libui gem directly into a **maintained Ruby version**:'. So, I tried on ruby 3.3.0 on another computer with just `gem install glimmer-dsl-libui' and it work fine! So you may have to try with **ruby 3.x** Good luck

Comment: @ludelle Oh. Yes. That could be it, after all 2.7 is ancient. Thanks, will try!

Comment: I managed to install Ruby 3.2.3 after some problems with rvm. Now I get a stacktrace of epic dimensions. My problem is that rvm won't install ruby 3.2.3 due to some problem with openssl. So I tried a new package manager (in fact, I tried a couple of them), and somehow these two don't coexist. The stacktrace starts with `/Users/marion/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/digest-3.1.1/lib/digest.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000107ba05b0`, so `gem install` accesses rvm and the wrong Ruby version. *sigh*

Comment: @ludelle All right, I fixed it. You were right. It now runs with Ruby 3.2.3. Do you want to make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Glimmer description state

> Install glimmer-dsl-libui gem directly into a maintained Ruby version:

I got the problem with ruby 2.6.1 but it work well on **ruby 3.3.0** with just:

```
gem install glimmer-dsl-libui
```

So, you may have to try with ruby 3.x